# Installing software with support of earlier version of ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, updates, deb

I have Ubuntu 23.04 Lunar Lobster. I want to install Cloudflare Warp (https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/). Now, this software has support only till 22.04 LTS.
Is there any way I can install the software without having to downgrade my software?
When I use the instruction given on the website, I get

`Err:9 https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com lunar Release   404  Not Found [IP: 104.19.236.24 443]` 
Is there any way I can download the package as a .deb file? (I am presuming that a software written for 22.04 will also work for 23.04).

Comment: Ubuntu's full development cycle is two years, with the *development* of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS started just after 22.04 was released; thus 23.04 is more related to 24.04 than the prior 22.04 cycle. Why would software intended for one cycle/release (20.10-22.04) be expected to work on a subsequent cycle (22.10-24.04)?  Many packagers skip the non-LTS releases until the *development* cycle has completed it's changes and the final LTS of that work is released.

Comment: Instead of running `echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/ $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list`, you can try `echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/ jammy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list` Whether the software will work is anyone's guess